# Bluetooth Socket: read failed, socket might closed or timeout

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth

So I am getting this error: `W/System.err: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1`

I am trying on a Samsung Galaxy S4 (API 21) and S2 (API 16) to connect to a custom device via Bluetooth. Sometimes it works. I have no idea what happens.

I know there are other questions with answers, but I feel like I've seen them all.

- I can not use "createRfCommSocket" method from BluetoothDevice.
- My UUID is correct, since I know the UUID from my custom device.
- I can not programmatically enable and disable the BluetoothAdapter.
- I tried clearing the App Cache.
- It sometimes works after clearing the Bluetooth Cache.

So my code for connecting:

```
private class ConnectAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
            mBluetoothDevice = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(params[0]);
            mBluetoothSocket = mBluetoothDevice
                    .createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
            mBluetoothSocket.connect();
            mOutputStream = mBluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
            mInputStream = mBluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            try {
                mBluetoothSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        if (aBoolean) {
            connectDeviceCallback.onDeviceConnected(null);
            startReceiverThread();
            startSendingThread();
        } else {
            connectDeviceCallback.onError("An error occured");
        }
    }
}
```

Error occurs on `mBluetoothSocket.connect()`.

Comment: Google really need to fix this stupid message. 'Socket closed' is a completely different condition from 'socket timeout', and they are both different from 'connection closed', 'connect timeout', and 'connection refused'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My phone was too far away from the device to connect correctly.